# Merge or delete semi-duplicates in an array

Tags: duplicates, power-automate, dataverse

I need to either merge or delete semi-duplicates in a Dataverse table. I looked into duplicate detection there, but I couldn't figure it out. I want to point out that that might be the solution to this and might be easier than what I'm asking for here. If I could keep the duplicates from writing to the table in the first place, that would be better.

In Power Automate, I create an array out of the aforementioned Dataverse table. Particularly, I'm looking at objects with duplicate Order Number values. Below is an example portion of the array. These three objects have the same Order Number but different Schedule Date.

I will have this array sorted by the Schedule Date, because I want the Schedule Date to be the earliest. Using Power Automate, how could I merge these records or remove all but the first one?

[image]